# Função jQuery chamada por dois elementos distintos de uma vez

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Possuo o seguinte código:

```
<table>
[...]
<tr class=""> 
     <td class="col-md-2">
        10.1
     </td> 
     <td class="col-md-8"> 
        Teste 
     </td>  
     <td class="col-md-1"> 
        10 
     </td>  
     <td class="col-md-1">  
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remover" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirma">  
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>  
        </button>  
     </td>  
</tr>
[...]
</table>
```

JS:

```
function removeEvento() {
    jQuery(".remover").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var linha = jQuery(this).parent().parent();
        jQuery("#confirma").modal("show");
        jQuery("#sim").click(function(e) {
            linha.remove();
            jQuery("#confirma").modal("hide");
        });
        return false;
    });
}
function insereEvento(formName, codInput, valoresArray, tabela, item, pontos) {
    tabela.append(linha);
    removeEvento();
    return true;
}
```

- Ele é executado a cada vez que o botão apagar linha é apertado.
- Existe um botão deste tipo para cada linha de uma tabela.
- Estas linhas são inseridas por jQuery/JavaScript, logo não posso recarregar a página.
- Problema: Quando clico no botão apagar, abre uma janela modal, para apagar a linha, se eu clicar fora ou em não, o modal se fecha. O problema é que quando clico para apagar outro registro e o apago, o registro anterior também é apagado.

Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Mostra o html também, por favor. Você tem algum identificador único da linha que você quer apagar?

Comment: Não, para apagar eu estou fazendo o seguinte:
Pego o identificador pelo click, uso parent duas vezes, pegando o <tr>. E depois dou um linha.remove().

Comment: E onde você chama a `function removeEvento()`?

Comment: Na função insereEvento(). Nela eu adiciono um evento e chamo a função, pois do contrário não funcionava, acho que porquê o elemento era adicionado depois do carregamento da página, ai por isso chamando a função funciona.

Comment: Por favor, edite sua pergunta quando precisar adicionar mais código a ela.

Comment: Gabriel, se alguma das repostas te atendeu, marque-a como aceita que a pergunta fica concluída. Diferente de um fórum, o stackoverlow é um Q&A, onde uma pergunta é considerada "resolvida" quando uma das respstas é marcada como aceita.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que a cada vez que você clica no botão ".remover" você está criando um handler para o botão "#sim" com o valor corrente de "linha" (via closure). Dessa forma quando o usuário clicar no botão "sim" irá executar todos os handlers. Portanto, para arrumar isto você pode declarar a variável "linha" fora do escopo do handler e criar o handler do botão "#sim" somente uma vez:

```
function removeEvento() {
    var linha;
    var confirmaModal = jQuery("#confirma");

    jQuery(".remover").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        linha = jQuery(this).parent().parent();
        confirmaModal.modal("show");
        return false;
    });

    jQuery("#sim").on("click", function(e) {
        linha.remove();
        confirmaModal.modal("hide");
    });
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente @Cesar.

Answer (score 1):

Como você está usando uma tabela, faz o seguinte: altera a linha

```
var linha = jQuery(this).parent().parent();
```

e coloca no lugar isso:

```
var linha = jQuery(this).closest('tr');
```

Essa operação é mais "barata" e mais rápida.

Depois, o seu método `removeEvento` pode estar setando várias ações no mesmo botão do modal visto que, para cada vez que você abre o modal, você está adicionando um novo evento de `click`.

Na arquitetura que você definiu, você deveria limpar os eventos do modal antes de adicionar um novo.
Para limpar use `.off()`.

Seu código deve ficar mais ou menos assim:

```
function removeEvento() {
    jQuery(".remover").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var linha = jQuery(this).closes('tr');
        jQuery("#confirma").modal("show");
        jQuery("#sim").off("click", "**").click(function(e) {
            linha.remove();
            jQuery("#confirma").modal("hide");
        });
        return false;
    });
}
```

Documentação do off: http://api.jquery.com/off/

Documentação do closest: http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: boa resposta, apenas para complementar, a função `.unbind()` pode ser utilizada no lugar de `.off()`, pois recebe como parâmetro apenas o evento

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, irei testar mais tarde e retorno avisando.

Comment: Utilizar o `$.parents` em vez do `$.closest` seria mais adequado => http://api.jquery.com/parents/

Comment: @FelipeAssunção Na verdade não. `$.parents` irá retornar todos os pais do elemento que correspondem com o seletor específicado. Mesmo que neste cenário só exista um único pai `TR`, este elemento é retornado dentro de um `array`. Assim, para executar o `remove` o `jQuery` precisa percorrer o array de um elemento. `$.closest` retorna apenas um elemento. O `jQuery` executa a ação neste elemento apenas. Assim, usar `$.closest` tem o desempenho um pouco melhor.

Comment: @FReNeTiC, fiz do jeito que tu falou, não funcionou, continuou dando o mesmo problema. Fiz do jeito que o Cesar William comentou e funcionou.

Comment: @GabrielOraboniCarvalho Que bom que resolveu! :D

Comment: @FReNeTiC, muito obrigado pela ajuda cara.